# Bash - Easiest way to evaluate each line of a file and compare to desired range

Tags: bash, math

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this. I have 7 seperate file that need to be filtered through.

Here's is how I started the first but keep in mind I need to do this 6 more times.

```
While read line do;

Onenum="$(awk '{print $12}' file.txt)"

Onenumssum="$(oneadd="$(tail + n 1 num2.txt)" && echo $onenum + $onenumadd | bc

Onenumdiff="$(onesub="$(tail - n 1 num2.txt)" && echo $onenum - $1sub | bc

if [ "$line" -ge "$onenumdiff" -a -le "$onenumsum" ]; then
```

Then $line if qualified need to be pushed to save file

File to filer looks like:

```
655.5
600
654
650
656
655
672
657
655
671
Ect.
```

I want to look through this file and find on the number that falls with in + or - 1 of 655 so the out put file should look like

```
654
655.5
655
655
656
```

Comment: What is the filter supposed to be?

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code. Please run it through shellcheck.net first.

Comment: The code is working unless I made typos. But it doesn't look so

Comment: `While`, `If`... can't be uppercase.

Comment: Variable names starting with numbers?

Comment: You shouldn't _type_ the code here, you should copy-paste it from what you use.

Comment: It's not our job to decipher which errors are your typos.

Comment: @Aaron the filter is if it falls in the range via the if statement. File.txt is a price num2 is a small number. The two are to be added and subtracted to produce a high and low range. Now to filter the file.txt to find entries that fall in the range.

Comment: Unclosed command substitutions, missing arguments in your `if` condition, ...

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve]. At the moment, it's very difficult to work out how to help you.

Comment: @chepner I didn't post asking you find Waldo with my errors I asked for a more efficient method.

Comment: It's hard to work out an efficient method to accomplish an ambiguous task.

Comment: Waldo is at least moderately hard to find.  If you want improvements to *working* code, Stack Overflow is the wrong site; try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I edited the post. Let me know if there are any more problems. I will oblige

Comment: `600` falls within the range too! It is missing in output and also `655.5` is out of the range `-655` to `+655`

Comment: You still have variable names starting with digits. You still have syntax errors in keywords. That `tail` command still has syntax errors. Parentheses are still not balanced. The `if` statement is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks but it's the methodology I'm after not petty mistakes when trying to obfuscate and transfer code by way of mobile touch screen but thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
655.5
600
654
650
656
655
672
657
655
671
```

You can use a tolerance and absolute value difference from a target to filter:

```
$ awk -v tgt=655 -v tol=1 'function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
                         abs($1-tgt)<=tol {print $1}' file
655.5
654
656
655
655
```

And then redirect that output to the desired file:

```
$ awk -v tgt=655 -v tol=1 'function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
                         abs($1-tgt)<=tol {print $1}' file > filtered
```

Comment: This really is a gorgeous piece of code!!!! Furthermore you nailed my question to the tee. I feel obligated to go help someone else out because this was so helpful.